# CV cross validation score statistical inference

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation

Im reading Core Statistics by Simon N. Wood and on page 36 they reference this formula:
\begin{equation*}
AIC\approx CV = -2\,\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(y_i|\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{[-i]})
\end{equation*}
I was wondering where I could find a derivation for this result?

Here is the book: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~swood34/core-statistics-nup.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eswood34/core-statistics-nup.pdf)